What is white buildup at Kitchen drain P-trap connector?
I recently moved into a new place and noticed white buildup at/around the kitchen sink drain pipe at what I believe is the P-trap connection nut. What is it and how serious of an issue? If an issue how urgent?


That fitting/connection is or had been leaking and what you see is oxidation. You can see the water stains on the bottom of the cabinet and also running down the trap. Get a wire brush and clean off the whole area and monitor it to make sure it's not leaking. If this is a rental, run it by the landlord. Since it's a drain, leaking would normally only occur when water is running down the drain so it's not as serious as a leaking water line but should still be investigated.

It's Oxidation of the copper and brass.
It may just need cleaning and be Ok, or it could be signs of a slight leak. The marks indicate that at some time some liquid was seeping and running down the pipe from the joint.  That seeping may have ceased now.
Clean it with a little vinegar and water and keep an eye on it.
